# Where can I see the SwiftPM Manifest file definition?

Tags: swift-package-manager

It started as simple as that I would like to look up all possible providers. Which ones are allowed? 
However, where is the full struct definition?

Comment: I accepted the answer from bscothern. It might become outdated in the future but this seems to be the correct answer now. Regarding providers (this was the trigger question): right now there are only brew for Mac and the other one for Ubuntu. See https://github.com/apple/swift-package-manager/blob/d001fc6fc431ef30b8e1af211914e10a1cb9725f/Sources/PackageDescription4/Package.swift

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<s>There isn't a place that I am aware of where the documentation is hosted outside of the GitHub repo [here](https://github.com/apple/swift-package-manager/tree/master/Documentation).</s>

<s>I just dig through those and the actual implementation files if needs be to figure out what is available to me if I'm looking for/at new features.</s>

As of WWDC 2019 there is now documentation on Apple's developer website for the package manager. It is [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift_packages) at the time of updating this.